# Split search results into different Tables MySql php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%value%' ORDER BY name
```

and a result table:

```
 echo "<table class='table'>";

    if ($num==0) echo "<tr><td>Sorry, no items found.</td></tr>"; 

    else{   
       echo "<tr> <th>Nr.</th> <th>Name</th>";
       echo "<th>Description</th> <th>Image</th>";     

    $lf = 1;
    while ($dsatz = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>$lf</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $dsatz["name"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $dsatz["description"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $dsatz["image"] . "</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
        $lf = $lf + 1;
        } 
        }
 echo "</table>";
```

Now what I would like to do is split the results based on a value from a column "type" into two result tables. The idea is to sort the results under different headlines. Here the logic:

```
If value from type == '1' use Table1

If value from type == '2' use Table2
```

Any idea on how I can do this?

Thx in advance!
Seb

Comment: Issue two separate queries, outputting the results of each one separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** The logic way is to do **two queries**:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%value%' and type = 1 ORDER BY name
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%value%' and type = 2 ORDER BY name
```

and proceed populating each table separately.

--

**2.** Your second option is to **use a condition** inside the "while" part, in each table (**not recommended**):

First, copy your results:

```
$res2 = $res;
```

Then:

```
echo "<table class='table'>";

if ($num==0) echo "<tr><td>Sorry, no items found.</td></tr>"; 

else
{   
    echo "<tr> <th>Nr.</th> <th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Description</th> <th>Image</th>";     

    $lf = 1;
    while ($dsatz = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        if($dsatz['type'] == 1)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$lf</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dsatz["name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dsatz["description"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dsatz["image"] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $lf = $lf + 1;
        }
    } 
}
echo "</table>";
```

and

```
echo "<table class='table'>";

if ($num==0) echo "<tr><td>Sorry, no items found.</td></tr>"; 

else
{   
    echo "<tr> <th>Nr.</th> <th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Description</th> <th>Image</th>";     

    $lf = 1;
    while ($dsatz = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2))
    {
        if($dsatz['type'] == 2)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$lf</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dsatz["name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dsatz["description"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dsatz["image"] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $lf = $lf + 1;
        }
    } 
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Ok. I was thinking about 2 queries as well but thought it would be faster to use only one?!? Why would you not recommend the 2nd option?

Comment: I was just concerned about best practices. The process of copying the result-set can be dangerous if you are working with ruge data. If one of the options (or both) solve(s) your problem, please, don't forget to up-vote the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I was just waiting for your answer. ;-) I went with 2 queries and of course it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!